# How to make Ubuntu (or which other distro) offer support for laptops that turn into tablets?

Tags: unity, graphics, tablet

After reading a lot on linux, ubuntu, other distros. They all mention the pros and cons in a general way. Lubuntu can run on old computers, Ubuntu Mate is great for laptops, etc.

My question is specific. What's the Linux distro with best support for a laptop that can become a tablet (Like lenovo thinkpad yoga). Supporting things like:
- Multi touch touchpad and screen (allowing to pinch for zoom for instance)*
- Screen rotates as you tilt it, and the keyboard, trackpoint and touchpad get disabled when made into a tablet.
- Support for touch pen.

I've been using Ubuntu for a few years, and sometimes I try other distros very shortly. But while Ubuntu can detect touches in the screen, and you can try to fiddle with a number of settings and install a number of apps to sorta make it work sometimes... It doesn't really support multitouch screen the way windows does it for tablets.. And it just feels I'm wasting useful things!

*Note: I know many distros sorta support this. Ubuntu you can zoom in and out of you pinch with 2 fingers while pressing control, but this is not suitable for a table mode.. right?